# why I'm I getting this error: Wrong argument count for function call: 6 arguments given but expected 5.solidity(6160)

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

Here's the code. The Emit transfer line (In asterisks) is returning the error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 

contract Transactions {
    uint256 transactionCount;
    event Transfer(address from, address receiver, string message, uint256 timestamp, string keyword);

    struct TransferStruct {
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint amount;
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string keyword;

    }

    TransferStruct[] transactions;

    function addToBlockchain(address payable receiver, uint amount, string memory message, string memory keyword) public {
        transactionCount += 1;
        transactions.push(TransferStruct(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword));
    
        *emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword);
    }*
    function getAllTransactions() public view returns (TransferStruct[] memory) {
        return transactions;
    }
    function getTransactionCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return transactionCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest wrapping the entire code in a code block so it's easier to read

Answer (score 4):

In your emit you are trying to emit 6 elements .

But in your event function you are only accepting 5 elements

In emit "amount" is an extra argument

Comment: Totally missed it. Thankyou